# Learning the Faraday Http Library

Tags: ruby, faraday

I've been interested lately in the Faraday Http client library. I don't see much in the area of documentation or tutorials and wanted to know if anyone knows of any tutorials, blog posts or talks that go into Faraday?

Comment: I just learn from the examples. Yeah, Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it. I'm just using it, and posting questions somewhere when I'm having problems. But you should definitely use it, it's by far the best library for making HTTP requests. Also, be sure to check out the [faraday_middleware](https://github.com/pengwynn/faraday_middleware) gem. It's been really useful to me.

Answer (score 8):

This article gives some nice background: https://mislav.net/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/

Answer (score 0):

I would say [Faraday on Github](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) answers all your questions!